# Installation issue of xdebug and vim

Tags: vim, xdebug

I installed xdebugger and vim on my system to debug PHP scripts. I placed the debugger.py and debugger.vim in /etc/vim/plugin. But when I open vim and press F5 it gives this error message:

```
Error detected while processing /etc/vim/plugin/debugger.vim:
line    1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/moises/.vim/plugin/debugger.py'
line   30:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'debugger_init' is not defined
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can we get a link to the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the following plugin: https://github.com/joonty/vdebug It's by far the best one and also best supported.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried installing vdebug, but again I ran into troubles. This is the error message that I get when I try to open Vim.

Comment: Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vdebug.vim:
line   32:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/start_vdebug.py'
line  111:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'DebuggerInterface' is not defined
Press ENTER or type command to continue